# How to find sum $\sum_{x=1}^K x^n(x-1)^m$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to find sum of this expression

$\sum_{x=1}^K x^n(x-1)^m$

where $n$ and $m$ are constants around $10^5$ and $K$ is a constant around $10^9$.

So my question is, is there a way to convert this sum in terms of a sum over $m$ and $n$ and not looping over $K$ as it is a very large value?

Actually I want to implement a computer program which tells the value of this sum by taking three inputs $n$, $m$ and $K$. I suspect that it could be reduced in terms of sum over $m,n$ using some binomial coefficients (maybe I am wrong).

Please anybody can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way we can break it to summation by parts?

Answer (score 2):

You can expand $x^n(x-1)^m$ as a polynomial in $x$ by the Binomial Theorem. Then the sums are given by the Faulhaber formulas, accumulating for the different degrees.

---

**Alternatively:**

The summation on this polynomial of degree $n+m$ gives a polynomial of degree $n+m+1$ in $k$. You can evaluate the sum for $n+m+2$ values of $k$ (e.g. the $n+m+2$ first integers) and form the Lagrangian interpolation polynomial. The coefficients can be found either by straight expansion of the terms (not recommended), by the Neville's algorithm, or by resolution of the linear Vandermonde system.

---

**Example:**

For $n=m=1$, the sums for $k=0,\cdots3$ are $0,0,2,8$, and the Lagrangian interpolation polynomial is the solution of

$$\begin{pmatrix}1& 0& 0& 0\\1& 1& 1& 1\\1& 2& 4& 8\\1& 3& 9& 27\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\2\\8\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}p_0\\p_1\\p_2\\p_3\end{pmatrix},$$

$$\frac{k^3-k}3.$$

Comment: Yes , actually I tried the first approach you suggested but after expanding (x-1)^m we will have m terms and applying Faulhaber formulas to each will consume more m+n calculations so my overall time complexity would become O(m * (m+n)) which does not help me. Sorry that I didn't mention that m and n are order of 10^5 and K is order of 10^9.

Comment: @AmbeshTiwari: what for a crazy problem is that ? Who needs to compute $x^{10^5}$ ?

Comment: xD , I mentioned that I need to implement a computer program which calculates this value efficiently. I just want to loop over 10^5 times of instead of looping over 10^9 times. I am looking at your alternate explanation though , It seems I can use it somehow.

Comment: @AmbeshTiwari: no, this takes $(n+m)^3$ operations !

Comment: Oh, yes that's more bad , :P , anyway thanks for your help

Comment: @AmbeshTiwari: this can be reduced to $(n+m)^2$ ny Neville's method, after evaluation of $n+m$ partial sums.

Comment: But O(K) is better than O($(n+m)^2$).

Comment: @AmbeshTiwari: I doubt you can compute the desired coefficients faster, and the "polynomial" approach doesn't sound that good. By the way, the complexity of the direct computation is like $O(kM(k)\log(n))$ where $M(k)$ is the complexity of the long multiplications, and the other complexities must be adapted as well.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the asymptotic for large $K$ we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(m,n,K) = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,x\, \le \,K} {x^{\,n} \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,m} }  =   \cr 
  &  = K^{\,n + m + 1} \sum\limits_{{1 \over K}\, \le \,{x \over K}\, \le \,1} {\left( {{x \over K}} \right)^{\,n} \left( {{x \over K} - {1 \over K}} \right)^{\,m} {1 \over K}}  =   \cr 
  &  = K^{\,n + m + 1} \sum\limits_{{1 \over K}\, \le \,{x \over K}\, \le \,1} {\left( {\left( {{x \over K} - {1 \over {2K}}} \right)
 + {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,n} \left( {\left( {{x \over K} - {1 \over {2K}}} \right) - {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,m} {1 \over K}}  =   \cr 
  &  = K^{\,n + m + 1} \sum\limits_{{1 \over {2K}}\, \le \,{y \over K}\, \le \,1 - {1 \over {2K}}} {\left( {{y \over K} + {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,n}
 \left( {{y \over K} - {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,m} {1 \over K}}  =   \cr 
  &  \approx K^{\,n + m + 1} \sum\limits_{{1 \over {2K}}\, \le \,{y \over K}\, \le \,1 - {1 \over {2K}}} \matrix{
  \left( {\left( {{y \over K}} \right)^{\,n}  + {n \over {2K}}\left( {{y \over K}} \right)^{\,n - 1}  + O\left( {{{n^2 } \over {K^2 }}} \right)} \right) \cdot  \hfill \cr 
  \left( {\left( {{y \over K}} \right)^{\,m}  + {m \over {2K}}\left( {{y \over K}} \right)^{\,m - 1}  + O\left( {{{m^2 } \over {K^2 }}} \right)} \right){1 \over K} \hfill \cr}   =   \cr 
  &  \approx K^{\,n + m + 1} \left( {\int_{x = 0}^1 {x^{\,n + m} dx} \; + {{n + m} \over {2K}}\int_{x = 0}^1 {x^{\,n + m - 1} dx}
  + {{nm} \over {4K^2 }}\int_{x = 0}^1 {x^{\,n + m - 2} dx}  + O\left( {{{nm} \over {K^3 }}} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  \approx K^{\,n + m + 1} \left( {{1 \over {n + m + 1}}\; + {1 \over {2K}} + {{nm} \over {4\left( {n + m - 1} \right)K^2 }} + O\left( {{{nm} \over {K^3 }}} \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$
Concerning instead other ways to recast the sum, of course there are many and it is 
difficult to understand which might better suit your goal, specially when you speak of $K$ being in the order of $10^9$.
Proceeding along the track above,  one could be to put the addend as
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{x^{\,n} \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,m} } \over {K^{\,n + m} }} = \left( {{x \over K}} \right)^{\,n} \left( {{x \over K} - {1 \over K}} \right)^{\,m}   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{x \over K} - {1 \over {2K}} + {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,n} \left( {x - {1 \over {2K}} - {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,m}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\xi  + {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,n} \left( {\xi  - {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,m}
  = \left( {\xi  + {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,{{n + m} \over 2} + {{n - m} \over 2}} \left( {\xi  - {1 \over {2K}}} \right)^{\,{{n + m} \over 2} - {{n - m} \over 2}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\xi ^2  - {1 \over {4K^2 }}} \right)^{\,{{n + m} \over 2}} \left( {{{\xi  + {1 \over {2K}}} \over {\xi  - {1 \over {2K}}}}} \right)^{\,{{n - m} \over 2}}
  = \left( {\xi ^2  - {1 \over {4K^2 }}} \right)^{\,{{n + m} \over 2}} \left( {1 + {{{1 \over {K\xi }}} \over {1 - {1 \over {2K\xi }}}}} \right)^{\,{{n - m} \over 2}}  \cr} 
$$
and then, from any point of the above,  to develop in series / sum.

Comment: Actually I am not concerned with it's asymptotic. What I want is to get the exact same value as we will get from $\sum_{x=1}^{K} x^n (x-1)^m $ by converting it in form of something like :  $\sum_{x=1}^{m+n}  C()... $  Basically I want to change the limits of iteration from K to m+n or something nearer

Comment: If possible It would be best to know a closed form of this relation  as that would make it O(1) calculation

Comment: @Don't know if I got exactly what you are aiming to: however I tried and indicate another way

Comment: Yep , thankyou very much :)